# CSS transition is going from left to right instead of right to left

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

[Video of the problem](https://webmshare.com/Pre6M) that is occurring (the animation in question is orange).

What is supposed to happen is that the search box will slide out from the right until it is full width, when the search icon is pressed. Eventually (when I code it) it will close again sliding back into the right side of the screen when the user unfocuses from the search box.

CODE:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mySearch').addClass('mySearchHidden');
  // $('#search').hide();
});

$('#myTouchSearch').click(function() {
  $('#mySearch').removeClass('mySearchHidden');
  $('#mySearch').addClass('mySearchVisible');
});









// $('#search').animate({width: 100+'%'}, 500);
// if ($('#mySearch').hasClass('mySearchOpen')) {
//   $('#mySearch').show();
//   $('#mySearch').transition({x: '+=100%'}, 500, 'ease');
//   $('#search').focus();
// } else {
//   $('#mySearch').transition({x: '+= -100%'}, 500, 'ease');
//   $('#mySearch').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend',
//     function(e) {
//       $('#mySearch').hide();
//     });
// }
```

```css
@import url("colors.var.css");
html {
  /*background-color: #212121;*/
}

.unselectable {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#myNav-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 64px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: #ef5350;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
}

.shrink {
  padding: 0 !important;
  font-size: 48px !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

input[type="search"] {
  height: 64px !important;
}

.input-field input[type=search] {
  display: block;
  line-height: inherit;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  width: 17rem;
}

#mySearch {
  display: inline-block;

  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.mySearchHidden {
  max-width: 0 !important;
}

.mySearchVisible {
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--Import materialize.css-->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />

  <!--Tell browser website is optimized for mobile-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <!-- Import index.css for custom styles-->
  <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Waukesha South High School</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar-fixed">
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-wrapper red lighten-1">
        <p id="myNav-title" class="brand-logo center z-depth-3 myNav-titleShort">SOUTH</p>
        <ul class="right">
          <li><a class="waves-effect"><i class="material-icons unselectable">people</i></a></li>
          <li><a id="myTouchSearch" class="waves-effect"><i class="material-icons unselectable">search</i></a></li>
          <li>
            <div class="input-field active orange" id="mySearch">
              <input id="search" type="search" required>
              <i class="material-icons">close</i>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>



  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <!--Scripts-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scrollNav.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/searchBar.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try giving `float:right` to your `mySearch` div/element.

Comment: You May Check it Here https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/slider-search-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can animate the width solely with CSS. I've created `a` [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/rnu4tc9x/1/) to demonstrate, including closing the search box again.